# getDay() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have the exact code from W3School.  While the code works on their website, it doesn't really work on my PC (Clicking the button does not produce any result).  I don't think the getDay() method from Date() object works properly, but I still can't figure out what the exact problem is.  Thank you in advance.

Original Link From W3School:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_switch

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display what day it is today.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var d=new Date().getDay();
switch (d)
{
  case 0:
    x="Today it's Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    x="Today it's Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    x="Today it's Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    x="Today it's Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    x="Today it's Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    x="Today it's Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    x="Today it's Saturday";
    break;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/eaDbV/

Comment: I literally just tested it and it worked check your browser and see if getDate() is compatible with it.

Comment: you should put a "default" case in your switch and make x = d

Comment: "I have the exact code from W3School"... it's OK, acknowledging you have a problem is the first step :P

Answer (score 1):

The sample is clearly fine, and it works on more than one machine I tried it with. Problem is on your machine.

Try this:

- disable antivirus/malware protection
- make sure your browser has no extensions blocking scripts (noscript, ghostery, etc).
- make sure your browser allows script execution

it would also help if you try using another browser.

Comment: He should also see what value he is getting  `make a "default" case in your switch and make x = d`

Comment: `disable antivirus/malware protection` ... really? This is bad advise.

Comment: @PaulS. I didn't say "uninstall". Obviously, something is blocking his javascript. Many "protection" suites are just blocking everything and his uncle.

Comment: @progenhard it doesn't seem likely to me that getDay() returns value outside of range. Much more likely scenario is that javascript never executes at all

Comment: I'm pretty sure Javascript is enabled on my browser, because I haven't had any problems running JavaScript until now.  I tried chrome and safari.  Weirdly enough, it just doesn't work for me.  Clicking the button still produces no result.  BTW, I'm using TextWrangler for all my coding.

Comment: @JYSuo Put a break point at like `switch(d)` and let us know what d is. (Should be 4, but it will narrow down the problem)

Comment: Hi, I finally make the code work on my computer.  I think the problem come from those invisible text marks and symbols.  When I copied the code from W3School and pasted to my TextWrangler editor, I thought I had exactly the same code.  But as I look at the code in 'view invisible' mode, I found out slight variations in terms of invisible marks.  After I hand typed the code again, it finally worked.  So the verdict here is "never be lazy and copy code".  I learned a lesson.  Thank you guys for the help! :D

Answer (score -2):

try this

```js
button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
```

instead of this

```
button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: The semicolon doesn't affect functionality in this context: http://jsfiddle.net/eBuPq/